# UIPresentationController changes size when another view controller is displayed on top of it

Tags: ios8, uikit, uipresentationcontroller, uitraitcollection, uikit-transitions

I am presenting a modal view controller using UIPresentationController. I am setting the frame of presentedView less than the containView's bounds using following method:

```
override func frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView() -> CGRect {
    let myDX = (self.containerView!.bounds.width - 600)/2
    let myDY = (self.containerView!.bounds.height - 600)/2
    return self.containerView!.bounds.insetBy(dx: myDX, dy: myDY)
}
```

Everything works great unto this point.

Now, I present another view controller modally (default not custom) on top of the currently displayed modal view controller which takes up the entire screen. So, I have a custom modal view controller underneath the default modal view controller that covers the entire screen.

The problem is when I dismiss the top view controller thats covering the entire screen, my custom view controller shows up covering the entire screen as well. I want my custom view controller's size to remain the same (smaller than containerView). Is there any way that I can achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe you can use autoLayout instead of hardcode the frame dimensions?

Comment: With iOS 12 I was able to solve this by changing the `presentationStyle` to `overCurrentContext` instead of `currentContext`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. I couldn't solve it by adding constraints, and `-[UIPresentationController containerViewWillLayoutSubviews]` is called too late (after the dismiss animation is completed).

After some time I figured out that the problem seems to be that the presenting controller view is being removed from the view hierarchy when you present with the default `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` `presentationStyle` and added again with a full screen size when it has to be shown again.

In iOS 8, you can use `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` as the `presentationStyle`  when presenting from the smaller controller. The system will not automatically remove the presenting controller's view then. (`-[UIViewController viewWillDisappear:]` and such, doesn't get called on the presenting controller when you do this though)

You can also use `UIModalPresentationCustom` which is available in iOS 7, but then you'll have to provide your own transition animation.