# UIPresentationController not calling containerViewWillLayoutSubviews until after display

Tags: ios, uipresentationcontroller

I have a `UIPresentationController` displaying a side menu over the main view with a fixed width of 300. Then from the side menu the user can open a full screen modal view. When the modal view is dismissed the menu view fills the screen during the dismissal animation (this is wrong). At the end of the animation `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews` is called and the menu corrects it's width to 300.

I do implement `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView`. I am also implementing `shouldPresentInFullscreen` returning NO on the menu view (though this seems to not affect anything I can really determine).

Why isn't `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews` called before the dismssal animation? How should I be maintaining the menu view's width when it is covered and revealed?

Comment: I think this question can help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792202/uipresentationcontroller-changes-size-when-another-view-controller-is-displayed/33385472#33385472

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to riadhluke for directing me to [UIPresentationController changes size when another view controller is displayed on top of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792202/uipresentationcontroller-changes-size-when-another-view-controller-is-displayed/33385472#33385472)

My solution is in my menu's `prepareForSegue`

```
UIViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
if (destination.modalPresentationStyle == UIModalPresentationFullScreen) {
    destination.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
}
```

Which forces fullscreen modal presentations to be Over full screen, which causes the menu not to be lost, and therefore not re laid out post dismissal animation.